# "How To Format" bar on Ask Question page is behind some content

Tags: bug, design, css

Here's what it looks like on The Workplace (tested and buggy in IE and Firefox):

[image: buggy workplace behavior]

Here's what it looks like on ELL (non-buggy):

[image: non-buggy ell behavior]
Steps to reproduce:

1. Navigate to https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/ask
2. Scroll down all the way

I imagine there's just a `z-index` or something that needs to be changed on the Workplace CSS file.

Comment: Agreed. It's buggy (at least in some browsers), unless that effect was the intent (unlikely).

Comment: Reproducible in FF/IE/Chrome for me so it does seem to be a CSS bug.